# Asus Memo pad 7 (ME170c) eclipse not picking device

Tags: android

I have bought Asus Memo Pad 7 (ME170c) today. I am not able to use it for debugging because system is not recognizing it. I also search for it's usb driver but i didn't found it even on their official site.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem with my MeMo Pad 10.

Try this : 
http://www.asus.com/in/support/FAQ/1004005/

If it doesn't work, download the drivers from here : http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/ASUS/ASUS-Android-Composite-ADB-Interface-Driver-8001-for-Windows-7-64-bit.shtml